# value is not a member of chisel3.Bundle

Tags: chisel

sbt does not recognize a bundle. Errors are these:

```
[error] /home/xxx/src/main/scala/NoC.scala:12:8: value Grant is not a member of chisel3.Bundle
[error]     io.Grant := io.Req & !io.Rls
[error]        ^
[error] /home/xxx/src/main/scala/NoC.scala:12:20: value Req is not a member of chisel3.Bundle
[error]     io.Grant := io.Req & !io.Rls
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/xxx/src/main/scala/NoC.scala:12:30: value Rls is not a member of chisel3.Bundle
[error]     io.Grant := io.Req & !io.Rls
[error]                              ^
```

Reproducible code is;

```
//Priority Encoder
class P_Encoder() extends Module {
    val io = IO(new Bundle {
        val Req         = Input(Bool())    //Requests
        val Rls         = Input(Bool())    //Releases
        val Grant       = Output(Bool())   //Grants
    })

    io.Grant := io.Req & !io.Rls
}
```

Probably I missed something on grammers, but not yet find out.
Does anyone can point out?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a change in type inference between Scala 2.11 and 2.12. You can work around this issue by adding `-Xsource:2.11` to your `scalacOptions` in your `build.sbt`. You'll see this in most chisel3 projects like the [chisel-template](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template/blob/2f98c1e079128e9124a8c59f022b284bbaea6cf6/build.sbt#L10), [rocket-chip](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/59349b711e4ac26189859eb48d97efec7f38405c/build.sbt#L17), and [sifive/freedom](https://github.com/sifive/freedom/blob/5241f55228e71589563ef9da46598cac06d34df6/build.sbt#L12). It's generally a good idea to create new projects from the [chisel-template](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-template/) until you are comfortable with the Scala ecosystem and the related tools (like SBT).

**EDIT March 2023**: This `-Xsource:2.11` trick worked for Scala 2.12, but does not work when upgrading to Scala 2.13. You can see some discussion of how to deal with this on the [Chisel website page for upgrading from Chisel 3.4 to 3.5](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/appendix/upgrading-from-chisel-3-4.html#value-io-is-not-a-member-of-chisel3module). As a general rule of thumb, the most robust solution is to name your Bundle types (rather than relying on anonymous, structurally typed Bundles), for the example above, change it to:

```scala
class P_Encoder_Intf extends Bundle {
    val Req         = Input(Bool())    //Requests
    val Rls         = Input(Bool())    //Releases
    val Grant       = Output(Bool())   //Grants
}
class P_Encoder() extends Module {
    val io = IO(new P_Encoder_Intf)
    io.Grant := io.Req & !io.Rls
}
```

Comment: [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading edu.berkeley.cs:chisel-iotesters_2.11:[1.2.5,1.3-SNAPSHOT[

Comment: [error]   not found: /home/xxx/.ivy2/local/edu.berkeley.cs/chisel-iotesters_2.11/[1.2.5,1.3-SNAPSHOT[/ivys/ivy.xml

Comment: [error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/edu/berkeley/cs/chisel-iotesters_2.11/[1.2.5,1.3-SNAPSHOT[/chisel-iotesters_2.11-[1.2.5,1.3-SNAPSHOT[.pom